# EXC_BAD_ACCESS accessing an NSMutableData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tcp, nsmutabledata

I´m getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I trying to acces to the data, I suppose it is because I trying to acces to the internal data, but I don´t know How to solve this, the code:

```
//data->NSMutableData

int identi;

[data getBytes:&identi];
NSLog(@"identificador: %i",identi);
```

Comment: it looks like you are trying to de-reference an int type when you write "&identi". shouldn't that be data getBytes:identi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/getBytes%3a),

> Deprecated in Mac OS X v10.6. This
>   method is unsafe because it could
>   potentially cause buffer overruns. You
>   should use getBytes:length: or
>   getBytes:range: instead.

The method is,

```
- (void)getBytes:(void *)buffer
```

**Parameters:** buffer

A buffer into which to copy the receiver's data. The buffer must be at least length bytes.

You are trying to save the receiver data into `identi`, a int value.

Comment: Thanks this solve the problem, code:   int identi;
       
[data getBytes:&identi length:4];
 NSLog(@"identificador: %i",identi);